# Automate setup of Win7 VPN, including registry settings and security policy changes

Tags: windows, vpn

After numerous difficulties I have managed to get a Windows 7 machine to connect to OSX Server's VPN.  I am looking to automate the setup process for Win 7 clients, which would include:

1. add one registry key
2. change couple security policy settings
3. configure a VPN connection (import a VPN profile??)

First 2 items above are per [OS X Server: How to connect to VPN service from Windows](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202384) article.

Is there a way to automate the setup so it is a single operation that can be performed by the user as opposed to me having to walk through all the steps on every machine?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some links on the Connection Manager to setup VPN connection and deployment to users.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc752995(v=ws.10).aspx

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2693643

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd672647(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Additional link: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd672647(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: If you want to add additional info to your answer, do it with the [edit] button. You don't necessarily have to comment to add info ;). Also, be sure to add summaries from external links, as your answer would become valueless if the links died